# Vertical wobble and flicker on analog oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, repair, crt, cathode-ray-oscilloscope

I'm using an old analog oscilloscope (Metrix ITT instruments OX 725).
(I don't have a printed manual for it, but you can find [scans of a French user's manual and service manual](https://www.doctsf.com/metrix-ox725/f73438?PHPSESSID=b6f1ad2ae39e5c3059dc403835153a9e) (with circuit diagrams) online.)

At some point, it has developed a fault, where the visible image seems to wobble and flicker vertically. Sometimes, it's a smooth movement up and down, sometimes it's quick flickering, sometimes both: (animated gif, may take a moment to load)
[image]

Here, both inputs are set to GND (instead of DC or AC coupling), and it affects both of them almost the same way, so I suspect the problem is somewhere with the vertical deflection of the CRT and not the signal input.

The strength of this effect varies while the oscilloscope is on (sometimes, it's not visible at all for a minute, then it only slightly wobbles, then it flickers strongly again).

**Does anyone with more experience have an idea what could be wrong or how to troubleshoot this?**
(If it's just a loose connector or faulty capacitor I would trust myself to be able to fix it, but anything else is probably out of my league.)

---

**Edit:**
If it's helpful, here are some photos of the inside of the 'scope. I can't spot any obviously faulty components, and I haven't found the courage to poke around in there.

> **Overview:** [image]
>
> **Mainboard & power supply:** [image]
>
> **CRT board:** [image]
>
> **Front panel boards:** [image]
>
> **Underside:** [image]

Comment: Your suspicion of an old capacitor should be investigated. Power supplies in these old analog 'scopes are complex, containing many electrolytic filter capacitors. A shotgun approach to replacing them would be onerous.

Comment: Old 'scopes also suffer from noisy front-panel variable resistors. If you tap, or rotate the **vertical position** control, is display affected? **Volts/Div** switch is also suspect for noisy contacts. Sprays are available - they *might* help.

Comment: How is synchronized the scope? Don't see the right of the scope ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
@glen_geek: The front panel knobs seem to have no effect on the noise (beside the act of switching the volt/div producing a short burst of noise when it clicks into place, which I think is normal). Have not dared to open it yet 

Comment: @Antonio51: Do you mean how it's triggered? I think in this case it was actually not triggered at all, but that does not influence the noise. I think it's independent from the actual signal being displayed and you can't trigger to it.

Comment: The video is useful...looks very much like intermittent noise source from rotating switches, or variable resistors. Track it down by tapping, wiggling things..but first, ensure you know where high voltage exists and stay away from that. Concentrate on the two Y-channel amplifier chains and the channel multiplexer that switches between them.

Comment: A nearly dead transistor in the Y amplifier supply would produce such noise. Is this a true dual beam or is it drawing the tracks alternating or chopped? What is the horizontal timebase in the video?

Comment: @Jens: From what I can gather from the French manual and slomo videos I took of the screen with my phone, I'm believe it's single beam and draws the traces alternatingly in this timebase (and chopped in slower ones). I did not write down the timebase, but I believe it was around the 0.2 ms / div setting. Different settings also have this noise, I'm not sure if it's different (it might flicker slightly faster on smaller times/div?).

Comment: I have now carefully opened it once. No obvious issues like blown capacitors, just *a lot* of dust which I vacuumed out. Also booped all connectors with a plastic stick once, but the issue still remains. (I don't feel confident enough to troubleshoot it while it is open and running (HV very scary) )

Comment: Do you see any electrolytic capacitors that appear to be bulging? Or any film capacitors with yellowing plastic branded RIFA? (Rifa capacitors are notoriously poor quality and should always be replaced as a matter of course--they tend to crack and even sometimes explode after a few decades, even when their ratings aren't exceeded.)

Comment: @Hearth: Thanks! Electrolytic no, but I did not know to look out for the RIFA ones. Will check again.

Comment: @Hearth: I looked inside again and also took pictures this time (see edited question). I see 4 film capacitors labeled `.1K1000` at the power supply and one `.1J400` on the CRT board. One of the formers (lower right in the pictures) seems a bit unevenly discoloured (or unevenly full of dust :D) on the side (at first I thought the plastic was warped, but I think it's actually just color), otherwise they don't look suspicious to me. I can find no association with RIFA when googling the markings. Do you think I should try to unsolder and check those?

Comment: Seems fairly safe, high voltage probably just in the back and on the CRT board. There should be ~100V somewhere on the main board as well, mostly near the CRT connectors.  I don't see any EHT, highest is probably under 2kV. Looks pretty low bandwidth too (unimpressive deflection transistors). (Ah, 10MHz bandwidth, that would do it.) I also see service manuals available online; have you checked for them? They'll do more than we can at a glance.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thank you for the advice. It's good to hear that the voltages are not super high, I also think the highest label I've seen is the 2kV next to the power supply capacitors. I've checked the service manuals, the most comprehensive scan I could find is linked at the top of the question. Unfortunately, there ist not much in there besides circuit diagrams and some PCB layouts. I could not find info on what all the potentiometers control, or what a calibration procedure would look like, or what the values of all components should be, or how to disassemble it beyond cover removal. :/

Comment: I guess the next step in troubleshooting would then be to run it while open, poke components with a non-conductive stick and see if something changes, like @glen_geek suggested?

Answer (score 3):

Those two vertically-mounted PCB contain front-end circuits for:

- Channel #1 vertical amplifier
- Channel #2 vertical amplifier
- Timebase for sweeping
- Triggering?

Those two vertically-mounted PCB are likely powered by low-voltage DC - fairly safe to probe.

CRT traces are jumping vertically in intermittent-fashion. However, note that they jump in tandem, so whatever is making them jump is common to Channel 1 and to Channel 2. It is not apparent if horizontal sweep has been set to **alternate** or to **chop**. OP's camera video may also affect this.

Tandem-jumping may mean that this intermittent noise is introduced later in the Y-channel signal chain (after alternate/chop multiplexing)...right up to the connection to CRT's Y-deflection plates.
Tandem-jumping might also involve a DC supply to CRT at its back end (a dangerous spot to probe). It might also involve low-voltage DC supply to those two vertical boards.
[image: annotated OP image]
Much dust has collected - ingress into switches and into those small black trimpots might cause intermittents.

Any wiping contacts might have oxidized - simply exercising these (breaking through the oxide) might be a fix. It is possible that vertical CRT plates are connected directly through the CRT's glass envelope (under the metal shield) rather than through its back-end. Hard to see from those excellent photos.
You might risk re-seating C.R.T. connections (V-plates) and back-end CRT socket. Wait a long time after the power plug has been removed before attempting this.

Are those two vertically-mounted PCB plugged into the horizontal PCB (rather than soldered)? If so, re-seat these. If soldered, carefully check that flexing hasn't damaged these joints.

Satisfy yourself where 2kV voltage exists. Seems that most danger is confined to the 'scopes back-panel area - you might shield this region with some non-conductive cover to keep hands, wayward tools from contact while you troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive reply and the advice. After carefully wiggling components in the running oscilloscope with non-conducting pliers and turning some of the relevant trimmers back and fourth, I can't identify any component that has influence on the noise (although it's hard to tell, since the noise pattern changes so erratically). Unfortunately, the vertical PCBs behind the front panel are soldered on the main board (I've also added a picture from the bottom now), connected with a bunch of shielding and seem very hard to dis- and reassemble without damaging something.

Comment: I noticed one more clue though: activating the beamfinder (which reduces the image to a flat, central line) produces a very stable image. This will probably help to narrow the problematic area down, but I don't understand some of the symbols used in the circuit diagrams and have to post another question about them.
I fear though that the problem ends up being in these front PCBs. I think I could reach a few more parts by removing the front cover, but that could also be important shielding? I may also try to contact the company who owns Metrix now, maybe they still have old service docs.

Comment: Two more points regarding your answer:
- The front PCBs barely flex even by hand, since they are fixed to the chassis with a metal rod going through the center of their top sides. The solder joints look fine to me.
- In your annotations of the image, you said to clean the rotary switches. How would you do this, besides exercising the switches? Compressed air? Maybe try to get some isopropanol droplets in there and then rotate them again?

Comment: Fii, Rotary V/cm switches get a lot of exercise - sometimes get noisy. Disassembly would be a royal pain. Simultaneous noise *on both channels* suggests a noisy switch or trimpot or contact elsewhere. You might work backwards from vertical deflection plates (stage by stage). That noise is jumping slowly enough to show up on a multimeter, making its needle twitch. Do be careful around vertical deflection plates - they are at a somewhat high voltage (but not kilovolts). I'd be reluctant to tackle this without a schematic. So close to useable - worthwhile poking around.