# Identifying different connector symbols in French circuit diagrams from the 80s

Tags: identification, connector, schematics, symbol, vintage

I'm [trying to troubleshoot](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686687/vertical-wobble-and-flicker-on-analog-oscilloscope) an old analog oscilloscope (Metrix ITT instruments OX 725), which seems to come from the late 1980s in France.

There is (part of?) a service manual with circuits diagrams available online (https://archives.doctsf.com/documents/afficher_document.php?num_doc=100437&num_fic=1), but I'm having a hard time piecing together how the circuits are actually connected.
In particular, there seem to be three different symbols used for '*this part connects to a different circuit*' that I can't identify. **Does anyone know what they mean and what the difference between them is?**

---

**Pill-shaped:**
These are the most common ones.

[image: Pill shaped symbol]

---

**Flag-shaped:**.
These kind of look like arrows. Most of them (but not all) have markings like `+12A` or `-12V` and point according to the sign of the number, so maybe they indicate connections to the power supply and some are misprinted?

[image]

---

**Double-angled-bracket-shaped:**.
These look similar to modern connector symbols, but not quite the same.

[image]
[image]

---

As an example, here is one of the schematics containing all three kinds of symbols:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A different opinion from Voltage Spike's...

Pill shaped - These are more likely connector pins.  Note the J#/Pin# format, as in J5 10.

Flag shaped - I agree that these are power connections.  I don't think the arrow indicates current flow, but rather source/destination (which may be the same a current flow, I guess).

Double-angled-bracket-shaped (double arrow heads?) - I think these are off-page connectors, for a multi-page schematic.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses:
Pill shaped - These are probably solder jumpers or resistor jumpers, or even 0.1" header jumpers.

Flag shaped - defiantly VCC/powerrail markers. The arrows could indicate direction of current flow

Double-angled-bracket-shaped - Not sure either, would need to see more, probably a test point or a different kind of power rail, maybe high voltage. Could even be comm

Comment: Double arrow ones may indicate that the signal moves to another sheet. All of them in the example schematic have diamond with a reference number next to them (e.g. `<F3>`, with the current sheet being `<F2>` according to the bottom left. Maybe they use `>>` for signals and `=>` for power.